# How can i optimize my database queryset in a django view

Tags: python, django, query-optimization, django-queryset

i've wrote a little blog script as a django app. I think in the single article view i have to many request. But i don't know how to reduce them.

I get all Blog posts with one query. As a result i get a queryset. With this i make some more actions. But with every action, the django debbuger toolbar tells me, it hits the database again and again.

Here is the view:

```py
def single(request, slug):
    articles = Article.objects.all()

    article = articles.filter(slug=slug)[0]

    newer_article = list(articles.filter(release_date__gt=article.release_date))[-1:]
    older_article = articles.filter(release_date__lt=article.release_date)[:1]

    return render_to_response(
        'article/single%s.html' % extend,
        locals(),
        RequestContext(request)
    )
```

- With the first hit i get the current article.
- The second and third hit is to get the article before and after

Is there a solution to get the same results only bei one database hit?

**Result:**

The new version on only 1 Query.

```py
def single(request, slug):
    articles = list(Article.objects.all())

    for i, a in enumerate(articles):
        if a.slug == slug:
            article = a

            if (i-1) >= 0:
                newer_article = articles[i-1]
            else:
                newer_article = None

            if (i+1) < len(articles):
                older_article = articles[i+1]
            else:
                older_article = None

            break

    return render_to_response(
        'article/single%s.html' % extend,
        locals(),
        RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce it to one query like so:

```
articles = list(Article.objects.order_by('release_date'))

for index, art in enumerate(articles):
    if art.slug == slug:
        article = art
        newer_article = articles[index+1]
        older_article = articles[index-1]
        break
```

Comment: You'll also want to add some error checking in case the article you're looking for has the earliest or the latest release date :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. :) And @abeinstein, thanks, i will keep it in mind.